# Github actions for renovate to read AWS Code Artifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, aws-codeartifact, renovate

We have a kotlin based repo in github and we are using AWS Code Artifact to store our private packages. I am trying to use renovate to check for dependency updates from AWS Code Artifact and create pull requests accordingly.

Knowing the fact that Renovate Bot (managed one) doesnt support the AWS Code Artifact, so I am trying to create a CICD for this and self host it using github actions. Below is my renovate.yml file content

```
name: Renovate
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/10 * * * *'

jobs:
  renovate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Install Renovate
        run: npm install -g renovate

      - name: Replace GitHub token in renovate-config.json
        run: sed -i 's/REPLACE_WITH_GITHUB_TOKEN/${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}/g' renovate-config.json

      - name: Run Renovate
        run: renovate --config=renovate-config.json
        env:
          CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

Here is the renovate-config.json file

```
{
  "platform": "github",
  "endpoint": "https://api.github.com",
  "token": "<token>",
  "repositories": ["githubuser/repnoname"],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": ["maven"],
      "registryUrls": [
        "https://domain-123456789.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/repo/"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But when the github actions running it is keep showing this error

```
 renovate --config=renovate-config.json
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN: ***
 WARN: Config needs migrating
       "originalConfig": {
         "platform": "github",
         "endpoint": "https://api.github.com",
         "repositories": ["githubuser/reponame"],
         "packageRules": [
           {
             "matchDatasources": ["maven"],
             "registryUrls": [
               "https://domain-123456789.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/repo/"
             ]
           }
         ]
       },
       "migratedConfig": {
         "platform": "github",
         "endpoint": "https://api.github.com",
         "repositories": ["githubusr/reponame"],
         "packageRules": [
           {
             "matchDatasources": ["maven"],
             "registryUrls": [
               "https://domain-12345678.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/repo/"
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
error: unknown option '--config=renovate-config.json'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Any idea why? or is there any other way of doing the same. Ultimate goal is to config renovate to access AWS Code artifacts so it can create related PRs.

Comment: That looks like an issue with your usage i.e. `error: unknown option '--config=renovate-config.json'`. Are you sure it accepts that? See https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/blob/main/docs/usage/getting-started/running.md#global-config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here I am posting a complete working solution with self hosted renovate on github actions. Please note that this solution is for Kotlin/Gradle/Maven based repos.

Inside .github/workflows create a renovate.yml file with the following content. Change the placeholder values according to your needs. (Keep REPLACE_WITH_GITHUB_TOKEN and REPLACE_WITH_CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN as it is)

```
name: Renovate
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/10 * * * *' # Set the schedule according to your preference

jobs:
  renovate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 18.12.0

      - name: Install Renovate
        run: npm install -g renovate

      - name: Replace GitHub token in renovate-config.json
        run: sed -i 's/REPLACE_WITH_GITHUB_TOKEN/${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}/g' renovate-config.json

      - name: Replace CodeArtifact token in renovate-config.json
        run: sed -i 's/REPLACE_WITH_CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN/${{ secrets.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN }}/g' renovate-config.json

      - name: Run Renovate
        run: renovate
        env:
          RENOVATE_CONFIG_FILE: renovate-config.json
          CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

Now in the root of your repo create a file named renovate-config.json with the following content. ( Keep REPLACE_WITH_CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN here as it is too)

```
{
  "platform": "github",
  "endpoint": "https://api.github.com",
  "token": "<github token>",
  "enabled": true,
  "repositories": ["repoOwner/repoName"],
  "dependencyDashboard": true,
  "repositoryCache": "gradle-test-renovate-cache",
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": ["maven"],
      "registryUrls": [
        "https://domain-domainOwner.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/maven/repository/"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "hostType": "maven",
      "baseUrl": "https://domain-domainOwner.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/maven/repository/",
      "token": "REPLACE_WITH_CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN"
    }
  ]
}
```

This should be enough to make it work. Also if you have enabled the renovate bot on this repo or on the organizational level then in the root of repo you will see a file named " renovate.json ". Replace the content of that file with the following

```
{
  "enabled": true
}
```

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: you will also need a method to keep the codeartifact token fresh right, as it expires after 12 hours? similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74651597/1711188)

Comment: not if your cron job runs before 12 hours.